# How to except a control from validating when use ASP.NET validation controls?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, validation, controls

I have some Textboxs in my .aspx page which has some validation controls (for example `requiredValidator` control). I want to execute these validation controls when I click only on a special control but not others.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`CausesValidation=False`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.causesvalidation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the controls which should not trigger validation.

You can also use [validation-groups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424%28v=vs.140%29.aspx) to sepcify what should be validated.